# Windows 10 Taskbar Win+# Jump to Window

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

The <kbd>Windows</kbd>+[0-9] shortcut will jump to an application according to the ordering on the taskbar. I want this to work on a per window basis instead and disable grouping by application on the taskbar.

Are there any taskbar replacement or other utility that can do this? Is this possible via the APIs exposed to do with the taskbar?

Comment: @kelvinelove: Please use accurate edit comments. You are suggesting edits in large numbers with the comment "formatting and grammar", but you don't seem to be making any grammar changes. Also, please be more thorough: you've overlooked some obvious flaws that you should have fixed.

Comment: Okay, noted...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) does exactly this. The keyboard shortcut change is not advertised but it can ungroup windows and the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+[0-9] shortcuts work as I want them to.